# Not all updates can be installed, partial upgrade proposed

Tags: upgrade, package-management, update-manager

When I am opening Update manager, it writes, that "Not all updates can be installed" and partial upgrade proposed.

What does this mean?

[image]

Am I correct thinking that "upgrade" means changing Ubuntu version to higher than mine? Or this is mistype? I would like not to change OS version.

Simultaneously I had multiple problems with software repositories and keys, which were solved. Is this related?

Comment: Please provide any log output and descriptions of your former problems.

Best - try to invoke 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -u' in a terminal window.

Comment: Doesn't `dist-upgrade` mean what I don't want to do?

Answer (score 2):

This situation is nothing to worry about. It happens mainly when there are several updates in a row and you should see it solved without any extra work within a day.

It is almost never useful to "Run a partial upgrade" - better wait.

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get update` do **not** upgrade the system to the next version - the names are rather misleading, they come from how they were used in Debian-systems.