# Problem Upgrading - Wants to do a Partial Upgrade, Is this safe for my xbmc install?

Tags: 12.04, xbmc, partial-upgrade

Running software update gives me this:
[image]

Clicking partial upgrade gives me:
[image]

It seems that it wants to remove (at least some portion of) xbmc. Is this safe to do without effecting my xmbc install? I'm quite happy with the way that it works, but am tiring of ubuntu nagging me periodically that it cannot do this update.

My xbmc is 12.2 "Frodo".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not all updates can be installed, partial upgrade proposed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253843/not-all-updates-can-be-installed-partial-upgrade-proposed)

Comment: no, not really. I was concerned with preserving my xbmc user data performing this update. The answer on that would not have helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should be safe. XBMC stores its config files in your home folder (I believe), so having it uninstall and then installed again shouldn't change any settings unless it plans on overwriting your config file. I'd say back that up and then do the update. That way if it does overwrite your settings, you've got a backup.

http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Userdata

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure if this upgrade can be done safety. If you setup `apt-undo` you can undo your system upgrade so that in case of disaster rollback is possible.

[apt undo](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/apt-undo-a-simple-way-of-undoing-apt-actions.html)

Alternatively you can use portable **xbmc** from portablelinuxapps.org

Comment: `apt-undo` is a modifier package and it is not listed by official and/or canonical repos ...

Comment: It is very interesting. Is there any more reference to apt-undo? TS can take advantage from it if it really does undo perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

- First try/suggested following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -f install
  ```

  This will configure any pending package + updating repositories + fixing broken packages.
- Then run following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

You can visit Information about [**Partial Upgrade:**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/U+1/partial_upgrade)

```
I'm offered a partial upgrade, what should I do?

During the past few Ubuntu development cycles, we've been flooded with threads asking
for assistance related to issues caused by careless usage of the "Partial Upgrade" feature
of Update Manager, which hinted to a poor understanding of package management and the
way updates happen in the development branch.

In an effort to help with this situation, this document aims to clarify what a Partial Upgrade
is, and why, in most cases, you'll want to avoid it.
```

Comment: This comment is good because it has a link to Partial Upgrade documentation from http://wiki.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE PLEASE CLOSE SOFTWARE UPDATER GUI

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Type: `sudo apt-get update` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait to complete.
3. Type: `sudo apt-get upgrade` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait to complete.
4. Type: `sudo reboot` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait to reboot.

To free space **OR** remove old kernels [READ THIS ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tho it doesn't seem to address "Is this safe to do without effecting my xmbc install?" I've not asked anything about old kernels.

Comment: you want partial upgrade and indifferently for checkbox upgrade will install upgrade for your xbmc according to your software sources (also third party ppa) within Partial Upgrade.

Comment: due to if you want upgrade your distribution then your software needed to be compiled for new upgraded kernels. it is a norm.

Comment: @swift, do you even read the questions?

Comment: sorry time to time it happens

Comment: though nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused because the system was using the [nathan rennie-waldock PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ubuntu/xbmc-stable) for xmbc instead of the [team xbmc](https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) one which is now the official one.

I backed up the `.xbmc` folder in `/home` and let the update run.

After performing this partial update caused xbmc to be removed. I changed by PPA for xbmc to the official one and tried to reinstall to 13.1 (Gotham). However the xbmc-bin has been left kicking (note it was in the upgrade section, not remove in the original question) around so I first had to `sudo apt-get remve xbmc-bin`. Once done I could reinstall xbmc from the official PPA. My user data was preserved.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Note - I store my db into a mysql database, so YMMV. Additionally, this database had been upgraded to Gotham via another xbmc on the network. I'm not 100% sure this all would have worked without that being done prior.